# Autolayout code crashes when running on 64-bit iOS7.1 simulator

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitableview, arm64

Everything went well until the upgrading to Xcode 5.1, my app crashes when I try running it on the 64-bit iOS7.1 simulator, but still fine on 32-bit simulators.

The crash message goes here:

```
2014-03-18 16:58:31.451 MyApp[8645:90b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109391530 V:|-(5)-[UILabel:0x109390630]   (Names:     '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x109390060 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109391580 V:[UILabel:0x109390630]-(3)-[UIView:0x109390960]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109391600 V:[UIView:0x109390960(40)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109391650 V:[UIView:0x109390960]-(5)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x109390060 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x109398d10 h=-&- v=-&- UITableViewCellContentView:0x109390060.height == UITableViewCellScrollView:0x10938f8a0.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1093997d0 h=-&- v=-&- UITableViewCellScrollView:0x10938f8a0.height == TDStatusFeedCell:0x10938f590.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10939a4d0 h=-&- v=--& V:[TDStatusFeedCell:0x10938f590(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109391580 V:[UILabel:0x109390630]-(3)-[UIView:0x109390960]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The code caused the crash is a custom table view cell using autolayout, the cell has a dynamic height which will adapt the content height, here is my code for constraint setup:

```
-(void)setupConstraints {
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    _ivPhoto.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _lblTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _imageContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ivPhoto attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:40];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ivPhoto attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:45];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ivPhoto attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:10];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ivPhoto attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:10];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_lblTitle attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:60];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_lblTitle attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:-10];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_imageContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:-10];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_imageContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_lblTitle attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

    NSArray *verticalConstriants = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[_lblTitle]-3-[_imageContainerView(40@1000)]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_lblTitle, _imageContainerView)];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:verticalConstriants];
}
```

**EDIT**

(@Christoper)The code for cell height calculation goes here:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
TDNewsFeed *feed = _newsFeeds[indexPath.row];
if (feed.status) {
    _sizingCell.frame = tableView.bounds;

    _sizingCell.lblTitle.text = [feed title];
    [_sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [_sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [self.sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1;
}

return [TDReviewCell cellHeight];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` you return CGFloat and not float. float could cause zero height cells on 64bits which would also break your layout constraints. And I agree to Christopher - you should paste your code from cell height calculation.

Comment: Thank you, Andris! I just correct the 'float' to 'CGFloat', since Xcode 5.1 just gave me a warning on it, and now I get no more crashes!

Comment: Great that I was able to help. I had a very similar situation a couple weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints will only work if your contentView is exactly 53 + the height of _lblTitle. Perhaps the code that's calculating your cell height is getting a different height for _lblTitle than autolayout is? Is it applying the same left/right margins you're creating in the constraints?

Comment: Thanks, Christoper! I use a cell object of the same class to calculate cell height, so the constraints should be the same.

Comment: Can you post the code that calculates the cell height?